# How to reliably keep a voip app alive in ios?

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets, cocoa-touch, ios8

I have a voip app for ios, based on webrtc. I also have a signaling server made with nodejs. I can connect to the server and make calls without a problem. But tracking presence (online/offline) accurately is a problem.

Just for the record, here is a list of everything I did to ensure a stable connection:

1. Set the background mode "Voice over IP"
2. Flag the inputstream as a voip stream with "[inputStream setProperty:NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP
                                  forKey:NSStreamNetworkServiceType];"
3. Turned on persistent wifi by setting "UIRequiresPersistentWiFi" to YES in the plist file
4. I implemented "setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:" and I use it to send a ping to the server (unnecessary, but you never know...)

I created a small test app that does nothing more than connect to the server and respond to "ping" with the message "pong". This app sends "ping" to the server when the keep alive timeout handler fires and the server replies with "pong". I also created a simple test server that does nothing more than let clients connect, send "ping" to a client when I send "send_ping" to it via telnet and responds to "ping" with the message "pong".

[Here is my client code](http://pastebin.com/t50RUXbF)

What I expect is the following:

- Starting the app and signing in should create a persistent connection to the server (works)
- Telnetting into the server and typing send_ping makes the server send "ping" to the client and the client should send "pong" back (works)
- Putting the device in standby should have no effect on the above ping-pong mechanism (doesn't work)
- Putting the device in standby and unlocking it after a few hours, then sending a ping to it should make the client send a pong back (works)
- Turning off wifi on the client (without cellular enabled) should be detected on the server-side and kill the socket (doesn't work)

I log all messages from the server in a textview on the client with a timestamp, and sometimes when I put the device in standby the pings I send from the server just don't arrive at all. Sometimes it takes over a minute for the app to receive the ping message, sometimes it responds immediately. I don't understand why it is so random. Sometimes this undesired behaviour starts after mere minutes in standby mode, sometimes it goes alright for a while but breaks after 20+ minutes, sometimes all messages from the server arrive at once as soon as I unlock the device.

Push notifications and voip push notifications could be a solution, but they are also slightly unreliable. There should be a way to make this work 100% of the time.

Comment: Finally what approach did you go with ?

Comment: @Sandy We still don't have a 100% working solution, but we found some useful things. For one, CentOS had a part to play in our connections being killed, moving the node.js server to a Windows host solved 80% of our problems. We now use voip pushes to cover that last bit and it's nearly perfect now.